# Infinite loop slider jumps slides when control nav is set to hover/mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, mouseover, infinite-loop

I have an infinite loop slider that displays the next and previous slides under an overlay. The slider controls work when set to click, however when switched to hover or mouseover the slides lose their ordering if the cursor moves too quickly.

Here is the slider with a hover control nav. 
[Example](http://rocky-meadow-9234.herokuapp.com/index.html)

Here is the javascript:

```
    jQuery(window).load(function () {

var $ = jQuery;

tcarousel = {

    selectors: {
        container: '#hero_slider',
        viewPort: '#hero_slider .flex-viewport',
        slideUl: '#hero_slider .slides',
        list: '#hero_slider .slides li',
        activeSlide: '.slides .active',
        pagingNav: '.flex-control-paging',
        prevNav: '.flex-prev',
        nextNav: '.flex-next'

    },


    init: function (options) {

        this.item_width = $(this.selectors.list).outerWidth();
        this.slideLength = $(this.selectors.list).length;

        this.setOrderIndex();
        this.createPagingNav();
        this.reposition();
        this.createControlNav();
    },

    setOrderIndex: function () {
        $(this.selectors.list).each(function (i) {
            $(this).attr('data-order', i + 1);
        });
    },

    reposition: function () {
        //should be a better way to do this
        $(this.selectors.list + ':first').before($(this.selectors.list + ':last'));
        $(this.selectors.list + ':first').before($(this.selectors.list + ':last'));
    },

    createPagingNav: function () {

        var $ctrlNav = $('<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"></ol>')
        var str = [];

        $(this.selectors.list).each(function (i) {
            var $el = $(this);
            var title = $el.data().label;
            var isActive = $el.hasClass('active');
            var markup = '<li><a class="nav_label">' + title + '</a></li>';

            if (isActive) {
                markup = '<li><a class="nav_label flex-active">' + title + '</a></li>'
            }
            str.push(markup);
        });

        $ctrlNav.html(str.join(''));
        $(this.selectors.container).append($ctrlNav);


        $ctrlNav.find('.nav_label').mouseover($.proxy(this.navTo, this));
        $ctrlNav.find('.nav_label').click(alert('clicked item' + this));

    },

    navTo: function (e) {

        var $el = $(e.target);

        if ($el.hasClass('flex-active')) {
            return;
        }

        var index = $el.parent().index() + 1;
        var $slidesUl = $(this.selectors.slideUl);

        this.setPageNavToActiveByIndex(index);

        var $currentSlide = $slidesUl.find('.active');
        var currentIndex = $currentSlide.data().order;

        $currentSlide.removeClass('active');

        $slidesUl.find('li[data-order=' + index + ']').addClass('active');

        var totalPage = ($slidesUl.find('li[data-order=' + index + ']').index() + 1) - ($slidesUl.find('li[data-order=' + currentIndex + ']').index() + 1);

        this.slideByPage(totalPage);

        e.preventDefault();

    },

    createControlNav: function () {

        var selectors = this.selectors;
        var $dirNav = $('<ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li><li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul>');
        $(this.selectors.container).append($dirNav);

        $(selectors.nextNav, selectors.container).click($.proxy(this.goToNext, this));
        $(selectors.prevNav, selectors.container).click($.proxy(this.goToPrev, this));


    },

    setPageNavToActiveByIndex: function (index) {

        var $pagingNav = $(this.selectors.pagingNav);

        $pagingNav
                .find('.flex-active')
                .removeClass('flex-active');

        $pagingNav
            .find('li')
            .eq(index - 1)
            .find('a')
            .addClass('flex-active');
    },

    goToNext: function (e) {

        $(this.selectors.activeSlide)
            .removeClass('active')
            .next()
            .addClass('active');

        var index = $(this.selectors.activeSlide).data('order');

        this.slide('right');
        this.setPageNavToActiveByIndex(index);

        e.preventDefault();
    },

    goToPrev: function (e) {

        $(this.selectors.activeSlide)
            .removeClass('active')
            .prev()
            .addClass('active');

        var index = $(this.selectors.activeSlide).data('order');

        this.setPageNavToActiveByIndex(index);
        this.slide('left');

        e.preventDefault();
    },

    slide: function (dir) {

        var me = this;
        var $viewport = $(this.selectors.viewPort);

        if (dir == 'left') {
            left_indent = parseInt($viewport.css('left')) + this.item_width;
        } else {
            left_indent = parseInt($viewport.css('left')) - this.item_width;
        }

        $viewport.not(':animated').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 500, function () {

            if (dir == 'left') {
                $(me.selectors.list + ':first').before($(me.selectors.list + ':last'));
            } else {
                $(me.selectors.list + ':last').after($(me.selectors.list + ':first'));
            }

            $viewport.css({ 'left': me.item_width * -2 });

        });

    },

    slideByPage: function (num) {

        var me = this;
        var dir = (num < 0) ? 'left' : 'right';
        var num = Math.abs(num);
        var loc = (num * this.item_width) * -1;
        var $viewport = $(this.selectors.viewPort);

        if (dir == 'left') {

            var leftLoc = parseInt($viewport.css('left'));

            if (num == 1) {

                left_indent = parseInt($viewport.css('left')) + this.item_width;

            } else {
                $(this.selectors.list + ':first').before($(this.selectors.list + ':last'));
                $viewport.css({ 'left': (leftLoc < (this.item_width * -2)) ? leftLoc - this.item_width : (this.item_width * -3) });
                left_indent = parseInt($viewport.css('left')) + this.item_width * num;

            }
            loc = leftLoc;

        } else {
            if (num == 1) {
                left_indent = parseInt($viewport.css('left')) - this.item_width;
                loc = this.item_width * -2;
            }
            else {


                $(this.selectors.list + ':last').after($(this.selectors.list + ':first'));
                $viewport.css({ 'left': this.item_width * -1 });
                left_indent = parseInt($viewport.css('left')) - this.item_width * num;
            }
        }

        $viewport.not(':animated').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 500, function () {

            if (dir == 'left') {
                $(me.selectors.list + ':first').before($(me.selectors.list + ':last'));
            } else {
                $(me.selectors.list + ':last').after($(me.selectors.list + ':first'));
            }
            $viewport.css({ 'left': loc });
        });
    }
};
tcarousel.init();

});
```

Is there anything I can do to make it not lose it's spot?

Comment: It could have to do with the animations queueing up and blocking because the cursor is moving to quickly. Try adding `queue: false` into your animation calls and see if that helps.

Comment: I just tried adding 'queue: false' and it behaves the same. I also tried adding stop before the 'animate()'